# Is there a way to hold many type of pointer to function without reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, reinterpret-cast

I have some code that deal with many pointer to function of different signature. Here's a snippet:

```
#include <unordered_map>

// Simple type id system
template<typename> void type_id(){}
using type_id_t = void(*)();

// value type of our map. We reinterpret functions pointer to this type
using held_type = void(*)();

// actual function type.
template<typename T>
using funct_type = T(*)();

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<type_id_t, held_type> function_map;

    function_map.emplace(type_id<int>, reinterpret_cast<held_type>(
        static_cast<func_type<int>>([]() -> int { return 42; });
    ));

    function_map.emplace(type_id<double>, reinterpret_cast<held_type>(
        static_cast<func_type<double>>([]() -> double { return 9.4; });
    ));

    // later on

    // prints 42
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<func_type<int>>(function_map[type_id<int>])();

    // prints 9.4
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<func_type<double>>(function_map[type_id<double>])();
}
```

Is there a way to achieve similar result without significant overhead and without reinterpret casts?

Comment: You can definitely make it shorter by writing a proper extraction method doing most of the job, however completely getting rid of fancy casts probably is not possible.

Comment: Imagine there is a solution. How would the compiler know the return type of `function_map[key]()` without specifying it yourself? The return type of any function call must be known at compile time, but in that case, it would depend on the value of `key` and the state of `function_map` which are runtime informations. In this case, the key happens to be derived from a type name. It may be cleared if you change your example, for example by using an `enum` as the key instead.

Comment: Can you change function declarations or those are fixed? Otherwise you can reverse the approach and use always the same declaration. Casts are no longer required in this case.

Comment: @VTT I would be happy by just using `static_cast`. The thing is, `reinterpret_cast` are harder to maintain and catch errors. @FrançoisAndrieux unfortunatly, I cannot use an enum, I have an undefinite amount of user defined type.

Comment: I mean you can write a getter doing all the casts.

Comment: @skypjack I have full control over the declaration of the lambdas. However, I add the lambda in the list from a function template, where the type is defined by the user of this code.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I mean, can't you do something along [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E0dwP4GKD6yXaBbt) line and then dispatch to the right function from within `S`?

Comment: @skypjack this is an interesting solution. It would work for any situation that only needs to do a particular action for the type used in the function, much like a visitor. In my case however I need to return the type to the user of my code. If there's no easy way to do this without reinterpret cast it's okay too. I will need to document the usage and the reason why.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot So, something like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Xyx4okTfbAMxAjh6) would work? No `reinterpret_cast`, only `static_cast` as requested.

Comment: @skypjack that's interesting. I can already imagine many other similar solution.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Yeah, probably [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X4B6c3tXyoQrELtC). :-) ... Ok, I'm putting it in an answer. Hope it can help you.

Comment: You can use Boost.Any (to be incorporated into C++17 as `std::any`) which uses type erasure and hides all the nasty low-level casting from you. It's also not that hard to write it yourself if you can't use Boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rework a bit your functions, you could approach it by reversing the flow and removing the return type.
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void call(T t, void *ptr) {
    *static_cast<T *>(ptr) = t;
}

// Simple type id system
template<typename> void type_id() {}
using type_id_t = void(*)();

// value type of our map. We reinterpret functions pointer to this type
using held_type = void(*)(void *);

// actual function type.
template<typename T>
using funct_type = T(*)();

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<type_id_t, held_type> function_map;

    function_map.emplace(type_id<int>, +[](void *ptr){ return call(42, ptr); });
    function_map.emplace(type_id<double>, +[](void *ptr) { call(9.4, ptr); });

    // prints 42
    int i;
    function_map[type_id<int>](&i);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    // prints 9.4
    double d;
    function_map[type_id<double>](&d);
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X4B6c3tXyoQrELtC).

Probably you can use the type of the variable to pick the right specialization of `type_id` up when you query `function_map`. Just hide everything behind a function template.